# What do I set the default value as when adding a field to a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I added the field `user` which is a foreign key to another model called `User`. This field was added to the model called `Bid`. However, when I tried to migrate the changes, I got the message:

```
It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'user' to bid without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows. Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
```

Last time, I set it to `'user'` and got an error that stated: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user'`.

What should I set the default value as?

models.py:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you are creating a new field in your table. When creating a new field, existing rows need to be taken into consideration. Safest approach is to set it as `null=True` and handle the field later.

```py
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

However you may not want a `Bid` to have a null user. In which case I recommend looking into [how to write a custom migration](https://medium.com/quick-code/how-to-create-custom-migrations-in-django-610718f49ae2) to populate existing rows.

Another note: if the data you have in your table is not needed, you could consider dropping the table and rebuilding it or deleting your migrations and creating them again with `manage.py makemigrations` - again only if the data you have in your db is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a relationship via a new foreign key, you have two options

1. You make the new FK nullable and let it default to `NULL` (i.e. `None` in python). This way, legacy entries with unknown relations will have `NULL` as the FK, i.e. do not know their users.
2. You manually populate the legacy fields with the appropriate foreign keys to the `Bid` records. This requires that you have kept that information beforehand.